# Aligning my geometry object using the projection/transformation of an ee.Image object in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to align my geometry object with the projection and transformation of my own Earth Engine asset raster

```
var xmin = -1164.4524382716;
var ymin = 135224.794683317;
var xmax = -204.452438271604;
var ymax = 136184.794683317;

var cali_albers = cali_raster.projection();
var bbox_geom = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], cali_albers, true, false);
```

where `cali_raster` is the name of my ee.Image object and `bbox_geom` is my geometry object. `cali_raster` is a raster I created in QGIS after clipping a raster of the United States down to the extent of California then reprojecting it from EPSG:5072 (Conus Albers) to EPSG:3310 (California Albers). I imported it to Earth Engine after performing these tasks. Printing the projection information of `cali_raster` returns this:

```
Projection
type: Projection
crs: EPSG:3310
transform: [30,0,-423114.4524382716,0,-30,611204.7946833177]
0: 30
1: 0
2: -423114.4524382716
3: 0
4: -30
5: 611204.7946833177
```

The translation values seem questionable to me, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to know exactly why this happens after a reprojection. Sending this projection information into my `bbox_geom` object moves the geometry object southwest into the Pacific Ocean, far from my true area of interest. Why is this? When I map `cali_raster` in Google Earth Engine, it aligns perfectly with the California boundaries so I would think the same would be true if I were to pass the ee.Image's projection information into a different object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an `ee.Projection` to construct your geometry, Earth Engine applies the projection's transformation to the coordinates. In other words, `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax` are incorrectly scaled and translated based on the image's projection parameters, leading to a misplaced bounding box.

Because your coordinates are already in the correct projection, you want a transformation with a scale of 1 and a translation of 0 that will leave them unmodified.

You can accomplish this by defining that projection by hand:

```js
var cali_albers = ee.Projection({
  crs: "EPSG:3310",
  transform: [1 , 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
});
```

Or you can just provide the CRS when constructing the geometry, and Earth Engine will automatically build a projection with a scale of 1 and a transformation of 0:

```js
var cali_albers = cali_raster.projection().crs();
```

In either case, the bounding box should now appear in the location defined by your coordinates.

```js
bbox_geom = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], cali_albers, true, false);
Map.addLayer(bbox_geom);
```

[image: Bounding box near Lake Tahoe]